# ¿Esta correcto acceder a un modelo desde otro modelo en CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Hace unos días me surgieron algunas preguntas a partir de una funcionalidad que tuve que implementar.

> **¿Está correcto invocar a un modelo desde otro modelo?**
>
> **¿Afecta mi seguridad en algo?**
>
> **¿Es antifuncional?**

Me funcionó perfectamente, pero no se en cuanto pueda afectar el buen funcionamiento de la aplicación web.

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a tus interrogantes

**¿Está correcto invocar a un modelo desde otro modelo?**

Si por correcto te refieres a si técnicamente CodeIgniter lo permite: Sí desde CodeIgniter 2.0 se permite cargar modelos dentro otro modelo.
De que se deba hacerlo o no ya depende de ti, sin embargo CodeIgniter es un framework MVC, por lo que se recomienda cargar los modelos dentro de los controladores y ahí hacer toda la lógica del negocio, por lo tanto si quieres ser estricto en el uso de MVC deberías cargarlos en el controlador.

**¿Afecta mi seguridad en algo?**

No tendría por que afectar a menos que en el modelo estés usando malas prácticas en cuanto a seguridad SQL, en esta entrada puede leer algo sobre inyección SQL [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

**¿Es antifuncional?**

Tu mismo lo dices

> Me funcionó perfectamente.

Sin embargo desde el punto de vista de MVC no deberías hacerlo así.

Como criterio personal te diría que sigas lo que dice el patrón MVC, sino no tendria mucho sentido usar el framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yo cargo todos los modelos de la aplicación en el autoload.
Y sí, tengo funciones de un modelo que invocan a funciones de otro modelo para extraer un dato. 
Lo único a tener en cuenta es que cada modelo tiene que estar refiriéndose a una entidad concreta:

"Usuarios_model" debería tener todas las funciones referentes a usuarios create_usuario, update_usuario, get_nombre_usuario... pero no debería tener la función "get_pedidos_usuario" esa la pondría en el modelo "Pedidos_model" porque la información que quieres extraer en ese caso es sobre pedidos y no usuarios.

Esa es la única regla que yo uso.